# Lentidão na abertura de JFrame com Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, swing, netbeans

Bom dia à todos.

Tenho uma aplicação Swing que tem um JFrame utilizando Hibernate 3 para persistência em BD MySQL em rede.
Quando rodo pelo NetBeans, ele abre bem rápido.

Mas quando executo o jar construído em outro computador, esse JFrame demora demais para abrir, chegando a quase 1 minuto de espera. Estou desconfiando do Hibernate, mas porque no NetBeans abre tão rápido, em 1 ou 2 segundos, se ele também precisa acessar a rede para chegar ao BD ?

Desde já, obrigado à todos pela colaboração.

---

Entity Manager

```
private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = null;
    EntityManager entityManager = null;

    try {
        //Obtém o factory a partir da unidade de persistência.
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AtualizacaoCadastralPU");
        //Cria um entity manager.
        entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    //Fecha o factory para liberar os recursos utilizado.
    } finally {
        factory.close();
    }

    return entityManager;

}
```

Queries

```
public List<BeanTiposOcorrencia> buscaTipos(){

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("BeanTiposOcorrencia.findAll");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return query.getResultList();

}

public List<BeanSubtiposOcorrencias> buscaSubTipos(){

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("BeanSubtiposOcorrencias.findAllComTipo");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return query.getResultList();

}

public String buscaAtividade(String protocolo){

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("ResultAtividade.findAtividade");
    query.setParameter(1, protocolo);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return ((ResultAtividade)query.getResultList()).getAtividade();

}

public String buscaDetalhe(){

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("BeanSubtiposOcorrencias.findAll");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return ((BeanSubtiposOcorrencias)query.getSingleResult()).getDescricao();

}

public List<ResultAgrupamento> buscaAgrupamentos(){

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("ResultAgrupamento.findAll");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return query.getResultList();

}

public List<ResultDetalhe> buscaDetalhes(){

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("ResultDetalhe.findAll");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return query.getResultList();

}
```

Unidade de persistência

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AtualizacaoCadastralPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>entity.BeanOcorrenciasGsv</class>
    <class>entity.BeanTiposOcorrencia</class>
    <class>entity.BeanSubtiposOcorrencias</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxx"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxx"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxxxx"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show.sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>`

Já vi relatos de outras reclamações a cerca da lentidão do Hibernate em rede, mas minha maior dúvida é porque ao rodar no NetBeans essa lentidão não ocorre.

Espero ter melhorado o esforço de pesquisa e ter tornado minha pergunta clara e útil.

Comment: Sem ver o código fica dificil identificar o problema, adicione o código na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa trabalhar com transações em casos de apenas leitura de dados, logo, suas funções ficariam assim:

```
public List<BeanSubtiposOcorrencias> buscaSubTipos(){
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("BeanSubtiposOcorrencias.findAllComTipo");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Sobre a lentidão, verifique se não pode ser problema de DNS apontando direto para o IP do servidor, e também certifique-se de que a versão do *driver* conector do MySQL usada no seu jar seja mesma usada pelo NetBeans.

Ah, sobre sua *factory*, use **static**:

```
private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
private static EntityManager entityManager;

private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (entityManager == null) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AtualizacaoCadastralPU");
        entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }
    return entityManager;
}
```

Deste modo, você cria a conexão uma vez só, e não a todo momento, só certifique-se de fechá-las no fechamento da aplicação.